# RHEL 7.9 RPM Broken after FRESH install

Tags: rpm, yum, rhel7

I have installed RHEL 7.9 and I don't recall having this issue before but for some reason after installing the OS, and adding my account, and doing all the basisc such as enabling optional and epel etc.

RPMS are not working for me.
For example, let's say, I try to install Chrome via the RPM.
If I double click the folder, it will open the Application store, and say "Sorry, something went wrong"
If I try to RPM -i xxxxxxxx, it will tell me the failed dependencies. I try to search all fixes to my best ability but nothing fixes it.

Or when trying to install this CM7 RPM, it says that it is missing libstdc++.so.6

Honestly not sure why RPMs would be broken from a fresh install. Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You hardly ever want to install something using `rpm -i`. Always `yum install`. Or `dnf install` on RHEL8+.

Answer (score 0):

The good way to install locally available RPM's is to use command like:

```
yum localinstall file.rpm
```

The command will follow and install the depend packages from available repos.